# I need help in query builder c#- delete doesn't work

Tags: c#

I have a small project in c# and ms-access. I use query builder to manage my tables in ms-access.

The problem is, select query works great, update query works great, but delete doesn't work and there is no error message!

Please help.

```
 public DataSet Update(DataSet ds)
        {
            using (cn)
            {
                OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
                string queryString = "SELECT [taskId],[resourceId] FROM [mytable]";
                cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + _conStrName + ";User Id=admin;Password=;";
                OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(cn.ConnectionString);
                adapter.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection);
                adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = queryString;

                OleDbCommandBuilder builder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter);

                adapter.Update(ds.Tables["mytable";"]);

                return ds;
            }
```

---

```
public DataSet Update(DataSet ds)
        {
            using (cn)
            {
                OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
                string queryString = "SELECT [taskId],[resourceId] FROM [mytable]";
                cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + _conStrName + ";User Id=admin;Password=;";
                OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(cn.ConnectionString);
                adapter.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection);
                adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = queryString;

                OleDbCommandBuilder builder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter);

                adapter.Update(ds.Tables["mytable";"]);

                return ds;
            }
        ==================================
```

Comment: Please post the SQL code that is not working.

Comment: An example of the code you are trying to use would help, how else were you expecting people to diagnose your problem?

Comment: public DataSet Update(DataSet ds)
            {
                using (cn)
                {
                    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
                    string queryString = "SELECT [taskId],[resourceId] FROM [mytable]";
                    cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + _conStrName + ";User Id=admin;Password=;";
                    OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(cn.ConnectionString);
                    adapter.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection);

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
DELETE FROM Store_Information WHERE store_name = "Los Angeles"
```

Comment: I took the code from here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommandbuilder.aspx
I don't need to write "delete.......... " cause I use command builder

Answer (score 0):

If you are using OleDb try something like:

```
    public static int DeleteStudentInfo(long studentNum)
    {
        var cmd = new OleDbCommand("DELETE FROM Students WHERE studentID = @studentId");
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@studentId", OleDbType.BigInt).Value = studentNum;
        return CallNonQuery(cmd);
    }

    private static int CallNonQuery(OleDbCommand query)
    {
        int rowsAffected;
        var conn = new OleDbConnection(ConfigSettingsManager.DBConnectionString);
        query.Connection = conn;
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            rowsAffected = query.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
        return rowsAffected;
    }
```

Replacing ConfigSettingsManager.DBConnectionString with your connection string.